# Have an onEdit() function run whenever a cell value is changed in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a Sheet that has the following:

```
ID        ROW     STATUS  ......
3588053   4       NEW
```

The Data for **ID** and **ROW** are coming from an *External Spread Sheet* called **KDCAlerts**

The **STATUS** filled is changed with an **onEdit** command (or in this case **onMyEdit**) that executes when there are changes on **KDCLog**

The **ID** and **ROW** changes each time the External spreadsheet changes (ex: adding / deleting rows, etc.)

**What I need to do** is to fix this so that when **ID** or **ROW** changes, the **onMyEdit** **function** is ran.

How can I do this? Below is the code currently being used now.

Any help, hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

```
function creatTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "onMyEdit").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onMyEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}

function onMyEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "KDCLog" ) {
    var extSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1b5qiNxxxxxxxxxRuLf-8dTBgRU9cHLBbd2A");
      var extSH = extSS.getSheetByName("KDCAlerts");

  } else { return; }
....
....
```

**UPDATE:**

@doubleunary - thanks for  the response.

> It is unclear how the values in the ID and ROW columns get written to the spreadsheet,

There are 2 Files: **KDCLog** and **KDCAlerts**.

**KDCLog!ID** is populated as follows:

```
=IF ( ISERROR( INDEX(SORTN(FILTER({KDCAlerts!E:E,KDCAlerts!H:H, KDCAlerts!A:A}, KDCAlerts!D:D=E7),1,,2,FALSE),,3) ), -1, INDEX(SORTN(FILTER({KDCAlerts!E:E,KDCAlerts!H:H, KDCAlerts!A:A}, KDCAlerts!D:D=E7),1,,2,FALSE),,3) )
```

So, it is "pulling" from **KDCAlerts** using a function (being executed in the KDCLog worksheet).

Whenever the **KDCAlerts** change, the Value in KDCLog!ID also changes (**without manual intervention** - the **KDCAlerts** changes with the **adding of rows**).

> If you are using another script to write to the spreadsheet,  it is
> likely that no events get sent.

For the **STATUS** column, it is populated with an **onEdit** funciton (seen above)

> trigger events that can be monitored with an installable on change
> trigger.

Is there a sample on how this could work

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me, so KDCAlerts is where a user would manually input (which triggers the `onEdit()`) and KDCLog is just a display/storage?
What if you add some logic in KDCAlerts `onEdit()` to change the respective value in KDCLog as well? That way you can trigger your `onEdit()` on the source of the actual input.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `on edit` trigger here, because it fires only when the spreadsheet is *manually edited* by a user, regardless of whether you are using a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) or an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

It is unclear *how* the values in the ID and ROW columns get written to the spreadsheet, which is what actually determines whether you can catch those updates. If you are using another script to write to the spreadsheet, it is likely that [no events get sent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions).

If you are using another integration tool, it may trigger events that can be monitored with an installable `on change` trigger.

Comment: thanks for the response. I made changes to the post

Comment: The updated question tells that there is just _one_ spreadsheet file, and that values get put on `KDCLog` by a formula that refers to `KDCAlerts` in the same spreadsheet file. That means that no events get sent when the formula in `KDCLog` updates its results. The sheet that does change is `KDCAlerts`, and you could perhaps trigger on those changes, depending on _how_ those changes get made. Please edit your question so that it describes your _end goal_ and the _problem_ you have reaching that end goal. Remove the "quoted phrases" and "discussion" there. Use comments for discussion.